# How encrypted AWS PostgreSQL RDS works under the hood?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds

I read that when creating an encrypted AWS Postgres RDS, it encrypts the underlying EBS volume created for it, all read replicas, backups, and snapshots as well.

Also when I queried and inserted the data into DB, it worked same as unencrypted DB would and gave results in plain text.

I have some questions regarding how exactly it is working under the hood.
Here they are:

> 1. How does search work?

A simple value-based search can be performed by encrypting what to search and then search it on the encrypted RDS. But my search in PostgreSQL was also working on JSONB nested objects. How is that achieved?

> 2. How does a partial search work?

I was able to do a partial search(`like` query) on a name and address inside a JSONB object. How can a partial search be done on encrypted DB?

> 3. How does insertion work?

I have some JSONB columns in my PostgreSQL and I was able to partial insert on my JSONB objects. Its a cool feature of PostgreSQL but how was it achieved when the whole JSONB was encrypted?

PS: I have some knowledge of how DB works under the hood for storing and retrieving data but can't get my head around if everything is encrypted. Pardon me if I am completely wrong on some concepts.

I would really appreciate if someone can shed light on this as I was not able to find it on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 8.1: Encryption Options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/encryption-options.html)

Comment: Thanks. I believe its using Data Partition Encryption here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking this. The DB files on EBS volume do not appear to be encrypted from the perspective of the PostgreSQL process that is running on the RDS server. The encryption/decryption is happening at the hypervisor layer, and is transparent to any software running on the VM. All those things you keep asking how they work, work exactly the same as they would on unencrypted EBS volumes, because when the DB service requests information from disk it receives unencrypted data.

Think of it like going into the BIOS on your laptop and enabling some sort of encryption of your disk volumes. Would you expect that to break all database engines you tried to run on your computer? Would you expect all software to somehow know how to deal with your laptop's BIOS disk encryption? When you do that all the software you run on your computer (like PostgreSQL) doesn't need to suddenly be made aware of how to decrypt data on your disk, it is transparent to that software, appearing to the running software as if the disk is not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B. I didn't thought like this. I went and read encryption on top of filesystem here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_encryption.
If this is the case then encryption/decryption on the fly can take a performance hit for searching and updating records if the table or its index grows in size and cannot fit in memory all the time?

Comment: The topic of EBS encryption performance has been discussed already many times, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322670/encrypted-vs-unencrypted-ebs-volumes-aws I suggest you search for "AWS EBS Encryption Performance" in your favorite search engine.